# Facebook API - My informations for the share dialog don't print

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is javascript code to create a share dialog for facebook. The share dialog is well opened but not my informations.

```
FB.ui({
            method: 'feed',
            name: 'blabla',
            caption: 'an example',
            message: 'my message',
            description: 'fdfdfd'
        }, function (response) { });
```

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the message parameter - pointless anyway, because the message has to be user generated.

See the docs for the list of parameters: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.0